# Why leaves of my bean plant are as in this photo?

Tags: vegetables, leaves, beans

I've a "new" bean plant (1 month old) in a vase (20 centimeters radius).

I water it every day approximately for 500cl/1 liter of water.

I've used a new topsoil and for 2 times a bio compost (famous on Amazon).

But i continue to find leaves as follows:

[image]

What can it be and what can i do ?

Comment: Personally, I consider it normal. I never have perfect leaves, OTOH it doesn't seems to effect the production. I'm curious if somebody know the real cause. [bean leaves are particularly soft and weak]